# Cannot read get parameters using data() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing the link value in anchor tags "data-link" attribute. For example `data-link="http://localhost/test/384/1?search=vvcxv"`

When I try to read the value using data('link') function the get parameters are not reading. Please help.

```
$('body').on('click','a', function (e) {alert($(this).data('link'))});
```

Comment: show your code more detail

Comment: please provide a sample code of what you are doing right now

Comment: Do you get any error? as the code is correct.

Comment: @Dreamweaver The parameter is added using ajax

Comment: @user1690835 - if the parameter is getting added via ajax; then you have to fetch it via `$(this).attr('data-link')` way

Comment: then the event should be bind on success of the ajax request, is it the same way ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code sample. Looks like you forgot something...

```js
var dataLink = $("[data-link]").data('link');

$(".result").html(dataLink);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-link="http://localhost/test/384/1?search=vvcxv"></div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` in jQuery's `on` function is causing trouble. You could try this instead:

```
$('body').on('click','a', function (e) {
  alert($(e.target).data('link'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. See this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    alert($(this).data('link'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-link="http://localhost/test/384/1?search=vvcxv" id="mylink">My Link</a>
```